# ImageMagick White to Transparent Background While Maintaining White Object

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using PHP's [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to turn the white background of an image, transparent. I pass the image URL to this PHP script and it returns the image.

```
<?php

# grab the remote image url
$imgUrl = $_GET['img'];

# create new ImageMagick object
$im = new Imagick($imgUrl);

# remove extra white space
$im->clipImage(0);

# convert white background to transparent
$im->paintTransparentImage($im->getImageBackgroundColor(), 0, 3000);

# resize image --- passing 0 as width invokes proportional scaling
$im->resizeImage(0, 200, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

# set resulting image format as png
$im->setImageFormat('png');

# set header type as PNG image
header('Content-Type: image/png');

# output the new image
echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

These transformations work pretty well. However, if I have an image with a white object, it doesn't work very well as a result of passing a fuzz value to [paintTransparentImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php); which is how I am cleaning up jagged edges.

**Here's an example of the result, note the white sofa:**

[image]

If I don't pass a fuzz value, then I get a proper cut, but i'm left with messy edges:

[image]

I have attempted to use [resizeImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) in an effort to achieve what's called 'spatial anti-aliasing' (blow up the image really big -> use [paintTransparentImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php) -> shrink image back down), but I didn't notice any significant changes.

Is there something I can do to better handle these really white images? I've played about with [trimImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php) and [edgeImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.edgeimage.php), but I'm not able to get the results i'm after.

Worst case scenario, (though not ideal), is there a means of identifying if an image contains some percentage of a particular colour? IE. if image contains >90% white pixels then I could run [paintTransparentImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php) with a fuzz value of 0 instead of 3000 which would at least give me a proper cut.

Thanks.

Comment: Solved. Edited post to show solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Replace white background with some other colour first, then change that colour to transparent.

```
<?php

# get img url
$imgUrl = $_GET['img'];

# create new ImageMagick object from image url
$im = new Imagick($imgUrl);

# replace white background with fuchsia
$im->floodFillPaintImage("rgb(255, 0, 255)", 2500, "rgb(255,255,255)", 0 , 0, false);

#make fuchsia transparent
$im->paintTransparentImage("rgb(255,0,255)", 0, 10);

# resize image --- passing 0 as width invokes proportional scaling
$im->resizeImage(0, 200, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

# set resulting image format as png
$im->setImageFormat('png');

# set header type as PNG image
header('Content-Type: image/png');

# output the new image
echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

update in 2021 => imagick module version 3.4.4 (you're welcome :o) ):

```
$imgick = new Imagick($pathToFile);
$aTaille=$imgick->getImageGeometry();
$colorToTransparent=$imgick->getImagePixelColor(0,0); 
$imgick->borderImage($colorToTransparent, 10, 10);

$imgick->floodFillPaintImage("rgb(255, 0, 255)", 2500, $colorToTransparent, 0 , 0, false);

$imgick->transparentPaintImage("rgb(255,0,255)", 0, 100, false);

$imgick->cropImage($aTaille['width'], $aTaille['height'], 10, 10);

$imgick->setImageFormat('png'); 

# set header type as PNG image
header('Content-Type: image/png');
# output the new image
echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the exec command. It worked for me.
You can refer to [this](https://www.lifewire.com/convert-linux-command-unix-command-4097060) link,

```
<?php
    $rand_new = rand();
    $target_dir = 'yourFolder/';
    $imageName = 'yourImage';
    $image = $target_dir.$imageName;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($image,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $new_image = time().".png";
    exec("convert $image -fill none -fuzz 10% -draw 'matte 0,0 floodfill' -flop  -draw 'matte 0,0 floodfill' -flop $new_image");
?>
```

Comment: Exec() is a PHP function used to execute some external program. In this case, you are just using the command line version of ImageMagic. This is unrelated to the question.

Comment: Did he mention not to use CLI for his solution? I suppose this would help him to get what he is looking for.

Comment: Being that I am the author of the question, I can say that I've already solved the issue back in April of 2017, and that your answer to use "exec()" has absolutely nothing to do with my question my friend.

Comment: Ok, It might help someone else though .