# PHP Imagick remove noise only around text with white background

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

This is the code:

```
$img2 = new Imagick($tempName);
$img2->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img2->setImageCompressionQuality($setQuality);
$img2->despeckleImage();
$img2->writeImage($root . '/memes/' . $folder . '/' . $filename);
```

It makes text look better but blurs the image overall!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVyDg.jpg)

So is there a way to reduce noise only on white background / around text?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544467/imagemagick-white-to-transparent-background-while-maintaining-white-object

Comment: Please share an image so we can see what you are referring to. Thank you.

Comment: @Marty1452 I tried around with paintTransparentImage now, it actually just sharpened the fuzz :/

Comment: I updated the question with an image example @MarkSetchell

Comment: You can do that in ImageMagick 7 command line using color thresholding to select all the small gray dots around the letters and then make the image white where the dots are found using masked compositing with white. `magick img.jpg \( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \) \( -clone 0 -color-threshold "gray(200)-gray(254)" \) -compose over -composite new_img.png`

Comment: With your code I get this error: magick: unable to open image '\(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537. @fmw42 but the file is 100% there I tested it with another imagick exec command

Comment: Post your exact PHP command!  If you are on Windows, then remove the \. If running from PHP exec(), then be sure you have quoted your command or use escapes if needed. If your image is not in your working directory, you will need to provide the full path to the image.

Comment: Ok it works now, but it cuts away too much like bright sky becomes completely white with sharp edges, can you explain all parameters? Better just post it as answer

Comment: Your command is the correct solution! Post it as answer so I can accept! @fmw42